# I am using migrate

Tags: laravel

I've the following error :

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Fatal error:
>   Class 'AuthSetupTables' not found

I'm using modules and the class exist in the folder of migrations from the module auth

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please ask your question properly

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help on asking questions